# USB problem on Linux Mint 21

Tags: linux-mint, usb

[This is my system info](https://termbin.com/fxff)

`/var/log/syslog` outputs:

```
8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.021657] usb 2-4: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed. 
Oct  8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.021848] hub 2-4:1.0: USB hub found 
Oct  8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.021861] hub 2-4:1.0: config failed, can't read hub descriptor (err -22) 
Oct  8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.022021] usb 2-4: Failed to suspend device, error -19 
Oct  8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.201509] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 98 
Oct  8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.473682] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 99 using xhci_hcd 
Oct  8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.494446] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8046, bcdDevice= 1.00 
Oct  8 09:05:53 mindtrap kernel: [ 1247.494458] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0 
Oct  8 09:05:59 mindtrap kernel: [ 1252.654212] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
```

`lsusb` outputs:

```
Bus 002 Device 062: ID 0451:8046 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1462:7d43 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046d:c062 Logitech, Inc. M-UAS144 [LS1 Laser Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 17ef:6099 Lenovo Lenovo Traditional USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 413c:a503 Dell Computer Corp. AC511 Sound Bar
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0451:8044 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 07d1:f101 D-Link System DBT-122 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:eb2a HP, Inc HP Color Laser MFP 178nw
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2001:f103 D-Link Corp. DUB-H7 7-port USB 2.0 hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This happens constantly and slow down my computer (especially during boot / shutdow). It's about the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 062: ID 0451:8046 Texas Instruments, Inc.
```

It's a usb-hub integrated in my display (Dell U2414H) which has a soundbar and a (logitech) webcam attached to it. When I detach the screen's usb-hub cable from my motherboard the problem goes away, but then I have... no sound / webcam.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to connect the screen's usb-hub with a usb2.0 port of my mobo, the one we usually connect mouse/keyboard.

This resolved my issue.